# batch remove multi geometry in QGIS

Tags: qgis, kml, arcgis-online, batch, multi-geometry

I am looking to find a way to simplify multi geometry KML files into single geometry files. However, rather than include the extra shape into my single geometry, I would like to remove it.

At the moment, I open the files in a text editor and manually remove the parts I need removed.

In the example below, I am looking to remove the two parts highlighted in yellow. 
[image]
I create these files using ArcGis browser: create drive time area, then extract data based on city limits, and then manipulate them in batches in QGIS. The city limits I use are what create these multi-geometries.

Comment: Are these MultiPolygons or do you have geometry collections?

Comment: If all the parts you want to remove are smaller than the parts you want to keep, you can "select by expression" and then delete all the selected polygons at once. Use a selection expression like:  $area < (the area of the smallest polygon you want to keep).

Answer (score 4):

This is easy to do in qgis 3 - run the processing algorithm "keep n biggest parts" and choose to keep only the 1 biggest part.